# How can I publish my rtmp url to red5?

Tags: java, red5, xuggle

I am trying to use xuggle and red5 to generate streaming video in a browser.  As a first step I'm just trying to run a video through xuggle and have it show up on my red5 server.  The problem is I don't know how to configure red5 to hook up to my java code. I have this code here:

```
private static String outputUrl = "rtmp://localhost:5080/oflaDemo/";
private static String inputFilename = "/home/usr/jworkspace1/GetContainerInfo/aaa.ogg";

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  IMediaReader mediaReader = ToolFactory.makeReader(inputFilename);

  // create a media writer
  IMediaWriter mediaWriter = ToolFactory.makeWriter(outputUrl, mediaReader);

  // add a writer to the reader, to create the output file
  mediaReader.addListener(mediaWriter);

  // create a media viewer with stats enabled
  IMediaViewer mediaViewer = ToolFactory.makeViewer(true);

  // add a viewer to the reader, to see the decoded media
  mediaReader.addListener(mediaViewer);

  // read and decode packets from the source file and
  // and dispatch decoded audio and video to the writer
  while (mediaReader.readPacket() == null)
  {
    ;
  }    
}
```

That gives me an error that says:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: could not open: rtmp://localhost:5080/oflaDemo/
```

My question is how can I open up red5 to receive rtmp from my java program?

Answer (score 1):

i think port 5080 is http port.

> ### Ports
>
> By default, Red5 open the following ports :
>
> - 5080 (HTTP port - embedded Tomcat)
> - 1935 (RTMP port)
> - 8443 (RTMPS port)
> - 9980 (JMX port - admin and shutdown)

you should use port 1935 for rtmp